# Replacement Video Board for Mac Pro not recognized by Mac OS X

Tags: mac, graphics-card, drivers

My expensive video board in Mac Pro (early 2008) died. I couldn't afford a apples-apples replacement so I got a lesser board. It works for the BootCamp Windows 7 partition, no problem.

When I BootCamp to the Mac OS partition, I get a Mac spinning wheel for about 2 minutes, then the computer simply powers off.

How do I get the Mac OS to recognize the new board? Thanks, in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK you need a special firmware/BIOS for your video card. If there's no such firmware for the card you bought you should return it and get an "official" video card

[edit]
I found [an article](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/mac_pro/faq/mac-pro-support-pc-video-cards-sli-crossfire.html) that states that Macs require special drivers (well, we knew that) and firmware (that's what i'm saying here).

Comment: I don't think that makes sense, otherwise it wouldn't work with the Windows partition.

Comment: I don't know any details about the differences between "Mac" video cards and the default ones, but i know for sure, that (at least a while back) video cards for Macs required to be equipped with the correct firmware.